# algebraically closed field of order 11

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $f$ is a finite field of order 11. The question is :
Is there is an algebraically closed field of order 11? if yes, what is the element representation?

Comment: Finite fields are never algebraically closed.

Comment: Do you mean "of characteristic 11" rather than "order 11"? As in other comments and answers, algebraically closed fields cannot be finite.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a finite field $\;K=\{a_1,...,a_n \}\;$ , then the polynomial

$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-a_k) +1\in K[x]$$

has no root in $\;K\;$ ...

Comment: so what is the field extension of $f$

Comment: @rose What field extension of $\;f\;$ ? Do you mean its splitting field?

Comment: Let $f$ be a ﬁeld and $k$ a subﬁeld of $f$. The ﬁeld $f$ is called an extension of the ﬁeld K. We express this by
$f \diagup k$ and call $f \diagup k$ a ﬁeld extension or an extension ﬁeld. I really want to understand this

Comment: @rose I know what an extension field is, and using the same letter for an extension and for a polynomial is not a good idea. This stuff is rather involved and you'll need to read it in some book or good site.

Answer (score 2):

For any field $F$, we can construct its algebraic closure $\bar F$.

The field ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$ of *order* $11$ is unique, and is not algebraically closed. Its algebraic closure, however, is of *characteristic* $11$, probably that's what you are looking for.

For this, basically you have to take the union of the fields $F_{11^n}$ for all $n$.

For $F_{11^n}$, one way is to find somehow an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\Bbb Z_{11}$ - and then, adjoining a root $\alpha$, the elements will be expressible as polynomials of $\alpha$ of degree $<n$ over $\Bbb Z_{11}$.

Note also that there are even bigger algebraic closed fields of characteristic $11$, with as many transcendents as we wish.

Comment: yes, this what I'm looking for and I want to know how can get the algebraic closure field of order 11 please?

Comment: sorry I mean the elements of algebraic closure field of order 11.

Comment: See the edit. $ $